# shape map file decoding

Tags: actionscript-3, dictionary, shapefile

I recently started off on working with shape map files, I downloaded a few shape files from the internet, 
the files had the following extension .shp, .dbf, .shx which I am unable to decipher what these extensions are. 
Then I found some actionscript libraries to parse these files [here](http://code.google.com/p/vanrijkom-flashlibs/)

However I am not able to understand the documentation there.

But using some example files I was finally able to draw a map in actionscript.
However these are without latitudes and longitudes,

Is latitude and longitude information stored in shape files, if so, how do I extract the data?.
Or are there special shape files with latitude/longitude information encoded into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the x/y coordinates directly as long/lat.

Quoting from [The 'Pedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Overview):

> Shapefiles deal with coordinates in
>   terms of X and Y, although they are
>   often storing longitude and latitude,
>   respectively. While working with the X
>   and Y terms, be sure to respect the
>   order of the terms (longitude is
>   stored in X, latitude in Y).

It's not guaranteed that these coordinates are lat/long -- sometimes they can be pixels.  However, that's determined by the generator of the Shapefile -- nothing inherit to the Shapefile itself.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any examples for working with co-ordinates with Shape files, I haven't found any yet.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out [iLog Elixir](http://www.ilog.com/products/elixir/) which has Flex components for Mapping and an application to convert Shapefiles into Flex Map Objects.